# Convert signed int (2bytes, 16 bits) in double format. With Java

Tags: java, double, wav, signed, pcm

I've got a problem. 
In Java I need to read samples from a wav file.
The file format is: wav, PCM_SIGNED, signed int of 2bytes = 16bits, little endian...
The object reads the audio samples in BYTES and I need to convert this two bytes in one double value.
I tried to use this formula but it's not completely correct:

```
mono = (double)((audioBytes[k] & 0xFF) | (audioBytes[k + 1] << 8));
```

Comparing the results with Matlab I always notice differences between the real value in Matlab and the converted one in Java.
Can anybody help me please?
Thank you,
Dave

Comment: Do you have an example of a short sequence of bytes, what your expected output is, and what your actual output is?

Comment: If audioBytes[k] is a byte, audioBytes[k] & 0xFF == audioBytes[k], so the mask is useless.

Comment: If audioBytes[k] == -1, audioBytes[k] & 0xFF == 255 (after I pass the result to System.out.println anyway).

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong... and embarrassed :)

Comment: this is my expected value in Matlab: -3.295876945438848e-05, while in Java it comes: -3.0517578125E-5. The strange fact is that Matlab*32768 = -1.0800 while Java*32768 = .1

Comment: Giving us the expected value without the input values is not enough to reproduce the results.  We need the values of audioBytes[k] and [k+1]

Comment: ok sorry. b[k]=-1, b[k+1]=-1 with the result explained before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given us enough information to know why you're getting different results in Matlab and Java.  Usually you scale the short channel data [-32768..32767] to a double in the range [-1..1] which it looks like you are attempting to do.  Your java result: -3.0517578125E-5 is correct for the short value -1:  -1/32768.  I don't know why your Matlab result is different.  You haven't shown us how you are arriving at your Matlab results.

If you have a large sequence of bytes (which I'm guessing you do), and you don't want to worry about BIG-ENDIAN vs LITTLE-ENDIAN or shifting bits and bytes, let java take care of it for you:

```
import java.nio.*;
...
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(audioBytes);
buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

while (buf.remaining() >= 2) {
    short s = buf.getShort();
    double mono = (double) s;
    double mono_norm = mono / 32768.0;
    ...
}
```

[ByteBuffer.getShort()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getShort%28%29) reads the next two bytes of the buffer, takes care of the Little-Endian ordering, converts the bytes to a short, and positions itself for the next getXXX() call.

Comment: I think this method is the best one.

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing in MATLAB.  What code/commands are you running?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
double sampleValue = (double)(( bytes[0]<<8 ) | ( bytes[1]&0x00FF ));
```

(Change indices to swap little/big)

Answer (score -1):

Cant you just do most_significant byte * 256 + least_significant_byte and then cast to double?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, because byte values in Java go from -128 to 127.